# TCL error: extra characters after close-quote

Tags: tcl, tk-toolkit

I'm trying to evaluate certain expression. I have "pqr" && "xyz" in command. on evaluating the command, it gives an error: extra characters after close-quote.
I think tcl cant able to parse && after double quote. If this is the reason then how should i have to deal with double quote and &&?

Comment: Can you show the actual code which results in error? What you've shown here doesn't have much sense since "pqr" and "xyz" aren't boolean, so they can't be joined by &&.

Answer (score 2):

You're not giving us enough information.

A wild guess is that you were writing something like this:

```
expr "pqr"&& "xyz"
```

which does give the error message "extra characters after close-quote". This is because the interpreter tries to parse the command according to Tcl language rules, and one of those rules is that a word that starts with a double quote must end with a matching double quote. In this case, there are two `&` characters following the matching double quote.

Now,

```
expr "pqr" && "xyz"
```

(with a space between the double quote and the ampersand) is no good either. This is because the interpreter will remove any characters that have syntactic function as it prepares the arguments for the command. This means that the argument `expr` gets is the string `pqr && xyz`. When the `expr` command executes, it tries to interpret its argument as a string in a special expression language that *isn't* Tcl. In particular, unlike in Tcl strings that aren't boolean values or the names of variables of functions must always be enclosed in braces or double quotes, like this: `"pqr" && "xyz"`. So how do you get that? You always* brace the argument to `expr`, that's how.

```
expr {"pqr" && "xyz"}
```

means that `expr` gets the legal string `"pqr" && "xyz"`.

But the string `"pqr" && "xyz"` is still not valid, since the `&&` (logical and) operation isn't defined for strings other than strings that are equal to the string representation of boolean values, such as `expr {"true" && "false"}`

So, again we're stuck, because what you seem to be trying to do makes no sense. If you show us what you're doing we might be able to help you.

*) except when you shouldn't. Rare, expert level.

Documentation:
[expr](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/expr.htm),
[Mathematical operators as Tcl commands](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/mathop.htm),
[Summary of Tcl language syntax](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/Tcl.htm)

*Brace your expressions*

The [expr](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/expr.htm) command (and by extension, the commands `for`, `if`, and `while`, which use the same mechanism to evaluate their conditions) interprets an expression string that is constructed from its arguments. Note that the language of the expression string isn't Tcl, but specific to the `expr` command's expression evaluator: the languages share many syntactic forms, but are fundamentally different with infix, operator-based structure for the `expr` language and prefix, command-based structure for Tcl.

Letting the Tcl interpreter evaluate the arguments before passing them to `expr` can lead to

1. *double substitution*, which has security problems similar to SQL injection attacks.
2. iterative commands (`for`, `while`) getting constant-valued condition arguments, leading to infinite loops.
3. all substitutions (and thus their side-effects) always occurring while `expr` can selectively suppress some of them.

Therefore, it is almost always better to provide the expression string as a braced (escaped) string, which will *not* be evaluated by the Tcl interpreter, only the `expr` interpreter.

Note that while unbraced arguments to `expr` are allowed to be a invalid expression string as long as the argument evaluation transforms them into a valid one, braced expressions must be valid as they are (e.g. variable or command substitutions must be simple operands and not operators or complex expressions).

Another benefit from using braced expression strings is that the byte compiler usually can generate more efficient code (5 - 10x faster) from them.